# spring mvc 4 + thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

thymeleaf are new and trying to integrate it in spring mvc 4.

By following [this](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html#integrating-thymeleaf-with-spring) tutorial I ran into this problem:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver]for bean with name 'templateResolver' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-config.xml];
```

Now I'm sure you have all the necessary jars, could depend on what?
attached the configuration file.

spring-mvc-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="it.shakesoft.common.controller" />


 <bean id="templateResolver"
        class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
    <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="templateEngine"
        class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine">
    <property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver" />
  </bean>

  <bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
    <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine" />
  </bean>

</beans>
```

[image: jars]

Comment: Can you post your pom? It looks like its missing the spring4 defn - http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring4

Comment: I don't use maven, i add manualy thymeleaf-sping4-2.1.4 jar in classpath

Comment: can you confirm the classpath? Its not finding the jar

Comment: I confirm the classpath...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was the lack of jar of thymeleaf, I had loaded only to spring mvc 4.